# Get sub-html element in [innerHtml] | Angular 6 for highlighting text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, highlight

Angular 2/4/5/6:
I have a div :

The innerHtml is actually html that has multiple tags in it, for example:

```html
<H1> Title of note /H1>
<P> This is a example note </P>
```

How would I get the reference of these sub html elements inside the innerHtml on click or highlight in the typescript file in Angular?

The purpose of this is to add a highlight span to the highlight portion of a html element, and its very difficult to modify the innerHtml before it is recieved by the angular side.

I was wondering if there is a solution similar to using nativeElement, but since i can't add #var to any of the subelements I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Your best option is to use `nativeElement`. Why can't add a template reference variable (#var)? Maybe a bit more code/information on what you have so far?

Comment: Hey Deborah, the code I am getting is from my REST api, which is sending a formatted text file with all the html tags pre-inserted, and since its a Node module its ideal that I don't mess with it in the backend.  Thats why it would be difficult to add variables to the tags, since a module is sending all that data with no variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure of what you mean, but I would use a JQuery selector to add the class with the CSS style you want to apply to highlight the text.

If you don't want to use JQuery, you still can manipulate the DOM via document commands.